What type of crystal oscillator is this?
I'm familiar with the Pierce Oscillator, but the above crystal oscillator circuit is unfamiliar.

Does it oscillate?
The low output impedance of N1 does not load the crystal?

If anyone is familiar with that oscillator?
I'll be glad for any explanation of the theory behind the circuit.
Thanks to all,
The source for the above circuit is Elektor Book 75, and the link below.
The source link for the above circuit (pages 67/68)


Hmm. Too bad that the Droitwich transmitter no longer uses 200 kHz and is now 198 kHz. There goes the calibration step mentioned in the docs.


It should.

No it does not load the crystal, it drives it.


That's a common oscillator circuit. Many crystal manufacturer calls it the series resonant oscillator.
The reason it may look funny is that the inverters used to implement the oscillator are actually 7400 NAND gate TTL chips instead of some other inverter like CMOS.

What is the purpose of the resistors in N1 & N2?
Is it for biasing?
How does the circuit start to oscillate?

@yishaiabramov Yes the resistors are for biasing the inverter to proper DC operating point. The circuit starts oscillating like any other oscillator circuit, the initial jolt of biasing and the tiny noise and disturbances of the circuit get amplified but the crystal allows only the resonant frequency to pass and get amplified.

Thank you for the explanation, now it's clear :). I think I'll construct the circuit to learn more.
